# What does "gamer" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading this article. One MMA Fighter is talking about the other fighter.
I don't quite understand what he's trying to say about the other fighter.

> “At the end of the day, I’ll give it to Max, he’s a gamer,” Volkanovski said. “I’m sitting there trying to knock him but at the same time you’ve got to give him credit. It’s entertaining.

1. As I know, "give it to someone" means, punishing someone. And I assume that *gamer* means somebody who fights fearlessly.

Does this mean the following?

> Ultimately, I will punish him. He's a fearless fighter!

But then it doesn't make sense to me.

2. Also what does "I am sitting there trying to knock him"? Does "sitting there" mean "staying there?"

By the way, this is excerpted from [Alexander Volkanovski doubts Max Holloway’s long-term durability after Yair Rodriguez: ‘That chin’s going to go soon’](https://www.mmafighting.com/2021/11/16/22784269/alexander-volkanovski-doubts-max-holloways-long-term-durability-yair-rodriguez-chin-going-to-go-soon)

Comment: Please never use markdown syntax with quadruplicated emphasis like that; it’s far too noisy and distracting. ‘Mentions’ (references to word as words) should be set as simply as possible in *elegant italic*, or “quoted”  if you must. They should not be set in heavy bold, and you should **never *ever ᴇᴠᴇʀ*** set mere English in that **ᴇᴠɪʟ-ᴀɴᴅ-ᴡʀᴏɴɢ** `   ` reserved for computer code: we deal with words here, not code. You were doing all four at once, rendering your post **ᴛᴇʀʀɪʙʟʏ ʜᴀʀᴅ** to read—at best❗Less is more.

Comment: My first thought was the quoted speaker might not be a native Anglophone, because I'd expect nearly everyone to say *he's a **fighter*** in such contexts. But I see now he's Australian, so that's not the reason. I still think most of us would use ***fighter*** even in this exact context, despite that fact that it would be a potentially confusing "metaphoric" usage (as an idiom, ***She's a fighter*** means ***She's determined, She doesn't give up easily***, not that she's a literal "pugilist"). But perhaps Volkanovski is simply avoiding the normal word because they're "professional fighters".

Comment: "*As I know, "give it to someone" means, punishing someone*". Sorry, you already fell off the bus here. In the context of "*At the end of the day, I’ll give it to Max, he’s a gamer*" 'giving it to him' means conceding a point, admitting that Max achieved something, a minor victory or accomplishment.

Answer (score 1):

In context, "gamer" means he's a good participant in the sport of MMA, a worthy opponent.
"I'm sitting there" does not literally mean sitting, as they are participating in a fight. Alternately, if this is after the fight, he may mean he's making critical remarks about his opponent, but at the same time crediting him for his abilities as a fighter and entertainer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I hadn't heard the sense you cited, but you're right: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gamer) has "**gamer** a player who is game / especially : an athlete who relishes competition"